# Al colocar fecha a un datetimepicker muestra el calendario y no requiero que se muestre

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Tengo un problema con el plugin de datetimepicker ya que al colocar una fecha en el input me abre el calendario en la parte interior izquierda y uno quiero que se muestre.

¿Saben porque me esta mostrando el calendario cunado coloco una fecha al input?

Código que coloca la fecha de hoy en el input (Javascript):

```
$("#fecha-fin-ticket-filtro").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Código HTML:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha Fin:</label>
        <div class="input-group date" id="date-fin-filtro" data-target-input="nearest">
            <input id="fecha-fin-ticket-filtro" name="fecha-fin-ticket-filtro" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#date-fin-filtro"/>
            <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#date-fin-filtro" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form group -->
</div>
```

> Captura del calendario que se muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y excelente inicio de semana.